# User's search using Jabbernet

Tags: c#, xmpp

I've put the following code on a Jabbernet client I'm writing:

```
    private void Roster_OnRosterEnd(object sender)
    {
        QueryUser(new JID("lixo@icts.br"));
        QueryUser(new JID("abc@icts.br"));
        QueryUser(new JID("nilo@icts.br"));
        QueryUser(new JID("simone@icts.br"));
    }

    private void QueryUser(JID jid)
    {
        IQ search = new IQ(Client.Document);
        search.From = Client.User.ToString() + "@" + Client.Server.ToString();
        search.To = "search." + Client.Server.ToString();
        search.ID = "search2";
        search.Type = IQType.set;
        search.InnerXml = "<query xmlns='jabber:iq:search'><nick>" + jid.User + "</nick></query>";
        Client.Tracker.BeginIQ(search, new jabber.connection.IqCB(OnSearch), jid);
    }

    private void OnSearch(object sender, IQ iq, object data)
    {
        Error err = iq.Error;
        if (err != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Error " + err.Condition + " on querying user " + data);

        if (iq.Query.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No answer querying user " + data);
        }

        foreach (Element a in iq.Query) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Answer querying user: " + data + " --> " + a.OuterXml);
        } 
    }
```

The problem is: method OnSearch executes only once, no matter how many searches I tried to do. I guess that method would be executed once for each search I send...

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify... I'm trying to discover if an user exists and, if true, I can send an invitation, depending on the contents of fields contained in the VCard of the user that will receive the invitation and decides if the invite can be sent or not.

TIA,
Nilo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different ID for each request.  Your error is on this line:

```
search.ID = "search2";
```

Keep a counter, or just allow the IQ constructor to generate one for you.  In addition, don't bother to set the from address:

```
search.From = Client.User.ToString() + "@" + Client.Server.ToString();
```

Delete those two lines, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Joe. Using your tip the thing works. The problem I'm facing now: when I search for "<nick>", it seems that the xml sent to the server has all characters lowercase, and if the nick have uppercase letters, it is not found on search. I will investigate more, but if you have another tip I would like to know.

Comment: Updating: what really happens is the fact that the search for nick is case sensitive. Could the search being case insensitive?

Comment: That's a question for your sever vendor.

Comment: My server is Openfire 3.8.1. To get a quick solution, I'll force users' registration using all lowercase. It will solve my problem without the needing of more research, and time to research is something I don't have now. Thanks for your help, Joe.